Data Structure studying. Max heap. Sorting part, necessity of the second loop
We were given the code:
internal class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         int[] arr = { 10, 40, 30, 20, 10, 5, 8 };
         int n = arr.Length;
         int i;

         heapsort(arr, n);

         Console.Write("\nAfter heap sort the array is:");
         for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { Console.Write(arr[i] + " "); }

         PriotrityQueue(arr, n);
         Console.Write("\nAfter deleting the item from priority queue the array is:");
         for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) { Console.Write(arr[i] + " "); }

         Console.ReadKey();
     }

     static void maxHeapify(int[] arr, int n, int i)
     {
         int large = i; //supposedly element with index i is maximum
         int left_child = 2 * i + 1;
         int right_child = 2 * i + 2;
         if (left_child < n && arr[left_child] > arr[large]) 
             large = left_child;
         if (right_child < n && arr[right_child] > arr[large])
             large = right_child;
         if (large != i)
         {
             int temp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[large];
             arr[large] = temp;
             maxHeapify(arr, n, large);
         }
     }

     static void heapsort(int[] arr, int n)
     {
         for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
             maxHeapify(arr, n, i);
         for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) //this is the loop I do not understand
            {
                int temp = arr[0];
                arr[0] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                maxHeapify(arr, i, 0);
            }
     }

     static void PriotrityQueue(int[] arr, int n)
     {
         if (n <= 0)
             return;
         arr[0] = arr[n - 1]; ;
         n--;
         maxHeapify(arr, n, 0);
     }
 }    

The code (from my perspective) doesn't work as it is supposed to.
It works though if I remove the second loop:
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) //this is the loop I do not understand
            {
                int temp = arr[0];
                arr[0] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                maxHeapify(arr, i, 0);
            }

I looked through different sources and they use this second loop without explanation. I just do not understand why it is needed.
Without it, I receive the proper (again from my understanding of max heap) result:
After deleting the item from the priority queue the array is:30 20 8 10 10 5.
If I use the loop, I receive this:
After heap sort the array is 8 10 10 20 30 40  - this is just a sorted array in the ascending order
After deleting the item from the priority queue the array is:40 8 10 10 20 30 - this is not right
I am just trying to understand why the second loop is used here or why potentially it can be used for sorting.
Any ides are appricieted.

The point of heapsort is to sort using a heap, not only to build a heap.

The three first lines in the loop switch 2 array values.

If I use the loop, I receive this result:
Initial the array is:10 40 30 20 10 5 8
After heap sort the array is:5 8 10 10 20 30 40
After deleting the item from priority queue the array is:40 8 10 10 20 30.
If I comment the loop out, I receive this result (I think this one looks correct):
Initial the array is:10 40 30 20 10 5 8
After heap sort the array is:40 20 30 10 10 5 8
After deleting the item from priority queue the array is:30 20 8 10 10 5

After heapsorting, you no longer have a max-heap (coincidentally you do have a min-heap because a sorted array satisfies the heap property) so calling PriotrityQueue after heap sorting your array is not valid (so yes the result is wrong, but because you used the function wrong). You can call it after heapifying your array, which is not the same thing.

@user555045. The code was given to me. So I am trying to understand it. Can you please advise how to use it correctly?  It seems it works when I comment out the second loop. But I would like to know if there is a proper way to use the function you mentioned.

"How to debug small programs" might be worth a read.

For what it's worth, your code would be easier to read (for use C# folks) if you used standard C# naming conventions (e.g. MaxHeapify, not maxHeapify, etc.). You might also want to use Generics (using T[] where T : IComparable rather than int[])

@Flydog57, thank you for the advice. I will try to follow this naming from now on.  Strangely, we were given it this way.


I looked through different sources and they use this second loop without explanation.

This particular loop is explained in Wikipedia - Heapsort - Algorithm:

The algorithm then repeatedly swaps the root of the heap (the greatest element remaining in the heap) with its last element, which is then declared to be part of the sorted suffix. Then the heap, which was damaged by replacing the root, is repaired so that the greatest element is again at the root. This repeats until only one value remains in the heap.

Note that this reduces the size of the max-heap by gradually replacing it with the sorted suffix, to eventually end with only the sorted array. At that moment it is no longer a max-heap.

I just do not understand why it is needed.

Its purpose is to sort the array.

Without it, I receive the proper (again from my understanding of max heap) result

Yes, from the viewpoint of getting a max-heap. Not if your aim is to have an array sorted in ascending order.

If I use the loop, I receive this: After heap sort the array is 8 10 10 20 30 40 - this is just a sorted array in the ascending order

Yes, which is the purpose of heapsort.

After deleting the item from the priority queue ...

This is the misunderstanding: at this point it is not priority queue. You shouldn't use max-heap functions on something that is not a max-heap. The creation of a max-heap is just a temporary phase for getting an array sorted. Once that goal is accomplished, there is no more max-heap.

Remember that the largest element will be located at the root of the heap which is index 0 in the array representation. The second loop  repeatedly extracts the maximum element from the heap located at index 0 and swaps it with the last unsorted element in the array at index i. It then maintains the heap property by heapifying the rest of the heap. In heap sort, after building the initial max heap, the largest element is always at the root of the heap (which is at index 0 in the array representation). The second loop essentially performs the sorting by repeatedly extracting the maximum element from the heap (which is at index 0), swapping it with the last unsorted element (which is at index i), and then heapifying the remaining heap to maintain the heap property.
This is important to the heap-sort algorithm as it performs the sorting step.
The problem seems to be occurring when you perform priority queuing. In that case you need to heapify the array once again to maintain the heap property.

The heapsort is not related to the function PriotrityQueue. Also, as I understood, the heapsort destructs the heap structure and creates a sorted list.
Instead, we should have been given the code for MaxHeap (or you can name it in any other way) that is similar to the first loop in the heapsort. Also, I discovered another error there. It shouldn't be just n, it should be n/2.
